# softwareserial.h no such file or directory

Tags: c, arduino, bluetooth

Im trying to use my arduino due to transmit data to my pc. The arduino should pick up information from a sensor which should be transmitted via bluetooth to my pc. But i got a little problem, "SoftwareSerial.h: no such file or directory

```
`#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define RX = 0;
#define TX = 1;
#define PIN_SENSOR = 2;

SoftwareSerial Bluetooth(RX,TX); 

byte state = B00000000

void setup(){

    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(RX, INPUT);
    pinMode(TX, OUTPUT);

}

void loop(){


for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
    if(digitalRead(i+PIN_SENSOR) == HIGH)
    state += (1 << i);
}

Bluetooth.write(state);


} 
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, some code cleanup. After trying to compile the provided code, I ran into numerous errors. I have fixed them and the code below should compile:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define RX 0
#define TX 1
#define PIN_SENSOR 2

SoftwareSerial Bluetooth(RX,TX); 

byte state = B00000000;

void setup(){

    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(RX, INPUT);
    pinMode(TX, OUTPUT);

}

void loop(){


for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
    if(digitalRead(i+PIN_SENSOR) == HIGH)
    state += (1 << i);
}

Bluetooth.write(state);


}
```

If you still get the error about software serial library, try downloading the Arduino IDE again from here: http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software